# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'User' with an argument list of type '(snapshot: (DataSnapshot)) Swift 3

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3

After I update Firebase pod I got this Error :

**Cannot invoke initializer for type 'User' with an argument list of type '(snapshot: (DataSnapshot))'**

And here is my code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLd4j.jpg)

Any Idea to solve this ..???

```
func loadUserInfo(){

    let userRef = dataBAseRef.child("users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)")
    userRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let user = User(snapshot: snapshot)
        self.usernameLabel.text = user.username
        self.userCountry.text = user.country!
        self.userBiographyTextView.text = user.biography!

        let imageURL = user.photoURL!

        self.storageRef.reference(forURL: imageURL).data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (imageData, error) in
            if error == nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let data = imageData {

                        self.userImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        })

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

After I update everything to firebase 4.0.4 I got the error, here is the whole codes :

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth



struct AuthService {
    var dataBAseRef: DatabaseReference! {
        return Database.database().reference()
    }
    var storageRef: StorageReference! {
        return Storage.storage().reference()
    }


    // 1- creating the signup function

    func signUp(username:String,email:String,country:String,password:String,biography: String, pictureData:NSData!) {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {(user, error) in
            if error == nil {

                self.setUserInfo(user: user, username: username, country: country, password: password, biography: biography, pictureData: pictureData)
            } else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
            }


        })
    }

    // 2- create the set user info function

    private func setUserInfo(user: User!, username: String, country: String, password: String, biography: String, pictureData: NSData!)
    {

        let imagePath = "profileImage\(user.uid)/userPic.jpg"

        let imageRef = storageRef.child(imagePath)

        let metaData = StorageMetadata()
        metaData.contentType = "image/jpeg"

        imageRef.putData(pictureData as Data, metadata: metaData) {(newMetaData, error) in

            if error == nil {

                let changeRequest = user.profileChangeRequest()
                changeRequest.displayName = username

                if let photoURL = newMetaData!.downloadURL() {
                    changeRequest.photoURL = photoURL
                }

                changeRequest.commitChanges(completion: { (eroor) in
                    if error == nil {
                        self.saveUserInfo(user: user, username: username, country: country, password: password, biography: biography )




                    } else {
                        print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                    }

                })

            } else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
            }





        }


    }

    // 3- save the User info in Firebase

    private func saveUserInfo(user: User!, username: String, country: String, password: String, biography: String)
    {
        let userInfo  = ["Email": user.email!, "username": username, "country": country,"biography": biography, "uid": user.uid, "photoURL": String(describing: user.photoURL!)]

        let userRef = dataBAseRef.child("users").child(user.uid)
        userRef.setValue(userInfo)  { (error, ref) in
            if error == nil {
                print("user info saved successfully")
                self.logIn(email: user.email!, password: password)


            } else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
            }


        }



    }



    // logging the user in function

    func logIn(email: String, password: String) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let user = user {
                    print("\(user.displayName!) has logged in successfully")

                    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                    appDel.logUser()
                }



            }
            else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)

            }

        })
    }





}
```

Now I have 2 errors :

[here is the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KL0rX.png)

I tried to update `profileChangeRequest()` to `createProfileChangeRequest()` but didn't help

Here is User class:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

struct User {
    var username: String!
    var email: String?
    var country: String?
    var biography: String?
    var photoURL: String!
    var uid: String!
    var ref: DatabaseReference?
    var key: String?


    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
         key = snapshot.key
         ref = snapshot.ref
         username = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["username"] as! String
         email = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["email"] as? String
         country = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["country"] as? String
         uid = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["uid"] as! String
         biography = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["biography"] as? String
        photoURL = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["photoURL"] as! String
     }  
}
```

Comment: Write `let user = User` and try to let the auto completion do its jobs, either with `User.` (maybe `User.init`), etc.

Comment: How is your User class defined?

Comment: I thought I had some problems having a class named "User" when using Firebase.

Comment: @Jay Question updated

Comment: Let me try this again:  We need to know what your User() class looks like i.e. how it's defined in code. The User class is where your error is so please update you question with User() class code. Going forward, you may want to standardize on how you name classes. User_Class or UserClass or something to let the reader know that it's a class.

Comment: @Jay just edited

Comment: Did your podfile include pod 'Firebase/Auth'? Also the createProfileChangeRequest needs to be on the currently Auth'd user like this *let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()*.

Answer (score 1):

I think your user class is clashing with with the [FIRUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRUser) class which they changed from `FIRUser` to `User` in the 4.x SDK. Try renaming your user class to something like `LocalUser` and see if that helps, if it does then there's your problem

Comment: No. Xcode would give you a class redefined or other such error.

Comment: Just tested it, it wont give you a redefined error, it will just get confused... Worth a shot anyways I think @Jay

Comment: @Chris change User to other name solved the problem , thanks a lot you saved my live ...... thanks Jay also

Comment: @MohamadMa'ari good to hear. Would you mind accepting the answer in that case :)

Comment: @MohamadMa'ari Wow - that is really odd. I actually copied and pasted the User struct and code from here to a new project and it's working fine. Must be something causing the error to flag in this project and not mine. Good catch though!